# Use dynamic column name in where clause without executing a variable

Tags: sql, variables

I use SQL Server and have the following query:

```
declare @variable nvarchar(max)
set @variable = 'Fixed_Assets'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'Select ' + @variable + ' from table where ' + @variable + '= 1 '
```

But how could I still use `@variable` as a value and not a column name?

I want to add a column (`Name`) and then with the constant value of Fixed Assets

Comment: "SQL" (the query language) has no "variables" to begin with. So we need to know which DBMS product you are using.  See [why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly insert a variable as a column name into a command, but you can create a command as a nvarchar, concat another variable into it (in your case the column name), then use `Exec()` to run it.

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(10)  
SET @variable = 'YourColumn'  
DECLARE @sqlCommandText nvarchar(1000); 

SET @sqlCommandText = N'select * from table where ' + @variable + ' = ''1'''

Exec (@sqlCommandText)
```

Don't forget if you have a single quote inside a string in sql you need to escape them by doubling them up.

Comment: Note that the above answer is product specific.